# How to remove from a Linked list in Java?

Tags: java, list

So I wrote my own linked list (and list node) in Java as a part of a homework.

Now, I'm trying to erase entries, but the function is not working.

I know the concept:

- Search for node keeping the previous;
- Tell previous node to point to next node;
- Return or stop using the node so GC erases it.

For some reason it is not working. I can delete the node with the same value over and over. I'm afraid it is something related to Java pointers.

The code:

Node:

```
public class SimpleNode<E> {

    private E value;
    private SimpleNode<E> next;

    public SimpleNode() {
        this.value = null;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public NoSimples(E data, SimpleNode<E> ref) {
        this.value = data;
        this.next = ref;
    }
// Getters and Setters
}
```

List:

```
public class LinkedList<E> implements Iterable<SimpleNode<E>> {

    private SimpleNode<E> head;
    private int size = 0;

    public LinkedList() {
        this.head = new SimpleNode<E>();
    }

    public void add(SimpleNode<E> node) {
        this.addFirst(node.getValue());
    }

    public void addFirst(E item) {
        SimpleNode<E> nonde = new SimpleNode<E>(item, this.head);
        this.head = node;
        size++;
    }

    public void add(E value) {
        this.addFirst(value);
    }

    public SimpleNode<E> removeFirst() {
        SimpleNode<E> node = this.head;
        if (node == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            this.head = node.getNext();
            node.setNext(null);
            this.size--;
            return node;
        }
    }

    public SimpleNodes<E> remove(E value) {
        SimpleNode<E> nodeAnt = this.head;
        SimpleNode<E> node = this.head.getNext();
        while (node != null) {
            if (node.getValue()!= null && node.getValue().equals(value)) {
                nodeAnt.setNext(node.getNext());
                node.setNext(null);
                return node;
            }
            nodeAnt = node;
            node = node.getNext();
        }
        return null;
    }
// Other irrelevant methods.
}
```

Comment: The concept in Java is that if an object has no more references then the GC will clean it up eventually. In your case, all you need is to remove the object from your LinkedList and that is it. To remove from the LinkedList you just Iterate through the and call .remove() from the Iterator.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm trying to do that in the above code, but it is not functioning.

Comment: It seems like you are skipping over the first node in remove: `nodeAnt = this.head`. This means the first node is already "Anterior" before you even looked at it.

Comment: While "it is not working" is a classic error description in all kinds of issue and bug reports, it's not very helpful...

Comment: Please explain ["not working"](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: If I erase a value, if I erase once again, it works and returns the same entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple Problems :

1. Think if you have a list `1,2,3,4`. Now, if you try to remove `1`, your code fails.
2. `nodeAnt = node` should be `nodeAnt = nodeAnt.getNext()`. Remember, the're all references, **not Objects**

Also, a recursive way might be easier to understand. For example, Here is how I implemented it

```
public void remove(E e){
    prev = head;
    removeElement(e, head);
    System.gc();
}

private void removeElement(E e, Node currentElement) {
    if(currentElement==null){
        return;
    }
    if(head.getData().equals(e)){
        head = head.getNext();
        size--;
    }else if(currentElement.getData().equals(e)){
        prev.setNext(currentElement.getNext());
        size--;
    }
    prev = prev.getNext();
    removeElement(e, currentElement.getNext());

}
```

**Note**: I delete all occurrences of the Element, as I needed it. You may need it to be different.

Comment: Is System.GC realy necessary?

Comment: actually, no. It's totally up to the JVM when to free up memory, but I added it anyway. Doesn't make any difference. @TiagoSirious

Comment: System.gc() will be ignored if "-XX:+DisableExplicitGC" is set

Comment: Worked with some changes. Please, correct the algorithm (add instatiation of prev, for example) so I can accept the answer.

Comment: @TiagoSirious I am not understanding you. Does my code fail ? Could you give my the testcases at which it fails ?

Comment: Is prev global variable?

Comment: @TiagoSirious yup, I know it's clumsy, but it worked for me.

Comment: So, ok. There's the problem.